# How to Create Partial Classes from CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, partial-classes, objectcontext

I am working with an application that uses EF, in a code-first approach so there are several domain classes.

I am in need of getting access to ObjectContext.SavingChanges so I can operate on a few newly-added business rules.From what I have seen here on SO and in [Julie Lerman's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596807260) I need to create a partial class with the same name as the generated partial class(es) generated by EF.

I cannot seem to find the location of these generated EF classes. Without that I don't have class names or namespaces to use for my partial class implementation.

**Questions**

**1.** Where can I find these generated EF classes?

**2.** Once found, which one do I use as my partial class if I need to get access to ObjectState.SavingChanges?

Comment: In code first, what kind of classes are you expecting to be generated?  In our EF Code First projects we are authoring those classes ourselves and allowing migration to update the DB when the model changes.

Comment: 1. "Code First" means, that there's no class generation. It means, that you write entity classes yourself. 2. Assuming, that you're using `DbContext` API, you can access `ObjectContext` via `((IObjectContextAdapter)yourDbContext).ObjectContext`. You can do this everywhere you have `yourDbContext` variable, of from inside of your `DbContext`-derived type. You don't need partial classes for this. 3. Why do you think, that you need `ObjectContext.SavingChanges` to apply business logic? Looks like you're misunderstanding something.

Comment: @Dennis Good questions. When data is changed in some of the entity classes, we need to be able to detect that in 1 place and then update a datetime field in a different table so I thought Object.SavingChanges would be good for this. I know how to override SaveChanges() but have no clue about ObjectContext.SavingChanges

Comment: @Dennis No, "Code First" is a bit of a misnomer because the name IMPLIES that you create the classes first, but this need not be the case. You can generate the classes based on an existing database. Microsoft have even admitted that the name is misleading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/21/ef7-what-does-code-first-only-really-mean.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For partial class, you only need to create new class with the same name as your ef class and you need to mark them as partial **in the same assembly** as you define your ef context.

But, if you want to access SavingChanges(), you need to create your own class context by extending ObjectContext, so you can override  ObjectContext.SavingChanges() to add your own business process.

hope it will help you.

Comment: "if you want to access SavingChanges(), you need to create your own class context by extending ObjectContext" - no, you don't need it. This is a public event, and external code can easily subscribe it.

Comment: Sorry I mean  the SaveChanges() no the event SavingChanges() as you can't cancel your saving operation in SavingChanges event.

Comment: That answered my question about partial classes. Thanks